# java.io.IOException: Bad DNS address - in opening a HttpConnection

Tags: java, blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

I m opening a HttpConnection to a URL. Its working in simulator but when i try it in device, it gives "java.io.IOException: Bad DNS address" while opening the HttpConnection. I serached the forums but havent got the solution yet.

That URL is opening in Blackberry device Internet Browser but not getting the HttpConnection (HttpConnection is coming NULL) when i try through my code.

Comment: Does your device have a direct internet access?

Comment: Yes. URL is opening in Blackberry device Internet Browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this forum posting](http://www.quickim.com/forum/ftopic60.html) using a Google search.  Search the page for "Bad DNS address" and you will find a tip that may help ... or not.  Basically it is saying that you need to reset your Blackberry to get around an OS bug.

I've no idea if this tip is still current, or whether it could damage your Blackberry, etc.  Your risk ... not my problem :-)